# Alternative mirrors for Android's Kernel 3.0 since kernel.org is down?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source

I am looking for alternative mirrors for Android's Kernel 3.0 since kernel.org is down. Thanks in advance.

Note: Android's patched kernel 3.0 not the same as Linux kernel 3.0.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110867/where-is-the-git-repo-of-androids-kernel-source

Answer (score 3):

manifest.xml is not modified for github, so it's no so easy to sync the whole android project.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/

Comment: This was the only place I could find the code I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: I could not get the Gingerbread source to compile after finding discrepancies in the Codeaurora.org source code.. did it compile for you?

Comment: Well this has the source to some old kernels here : https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/common/refs/heads

Answer (score 0):

This is a mirror of the whole Android repository
https://github.com/android

Comment: Note that this is an unofficial mirror. I don't have a better answer, though.

Comment: Right, though by the nature of GIT every mirror is just as official if it has the same exact content

Comment: Yes but all those mirrors point to kernel.org                                                                                                   

#git clone git://android.kernel.org/kernel/common.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/work/linux/common/.git/
fatal: Unable to look up android.kernel.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)

Comment: Except the use of repo and the manifest system, makes android not so trivial to just clone, as a normal git repository would be.

Comment: @Phillip +1.  What a fscking buzzkill...