# Where is the git repo of Android's kernel source?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source

I want to build a kernel for my device from source, however I'm unable to find the git repo of the kernel source.

All I found is this:

```
git://android.git.kernel.org/kernel/common.git
```

But however it seems to be deprecated after the kernel.org fuss recently, with git prompting that

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Are they moving to somewhere or nowhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What was at `git://android.git.kernel.org/` can now be found at https://android.googlesource.com/.

I did the replacement in your URL, and this is the result:

```
$ git ls-remote https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git
844e64ac186e89d7721bcf6d98cbbce8e1002839    refs/heads/android-2.6.39
0d8f32b7e8e99f593d7d7ff1afac4e6320e1d5ab    refs/heads/android-3.0
```

I do not know if this is what you were looking for, but it is worth a look.

Comment: And by the way, if you clone the https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest the documentation mentions, you can see a few XML files which seem to refer to other repositories. For instance, when it mentions name="platform/build", you know there is a repository at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build. However, the kernel repositories do not seem to be listed there.

Answer (score 3):

[As the docs on Android say](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) you must use their own custom tool for handling Git called repo.

1. You need to make a directory where your repositories will be installed.
2. curl and chmod the shell script
3. repo sync # this will take a lot of time
4. source build/envsetup.sh
5. lunch
6. make -jN # where N is the number of cpus * the number of cores per cpu you have * 1.5

Comment: I am referring to the git repo of `Linux kernel` used in Android, not Android's own sources. Kernel source, by default, is not included there.